# I need some Text Parsing Help (Regular Expressions / C#)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, text-parsing

I could use a little help with proper regular expressions to parse the following string into 3 variables. The part with comments saying `// TODO:` is where I need help with the regular expressions. For now I have just assigned a static value, but need to replace that with real regular expressions that parse the sample text. Thanks!

```
// This is what a sample text will look like.
var text = "Cashpay @username 55 This is a sample message";

// We need to parse the text into 3 variables.
// 1) username - the user the payment will go to.
// 2) amount - the amount the payment is for.
// 3) message - an optional message for the payment.
var username = "username"; // TODO: Get the username value from the text.
var amount = 55.00; // TODO: Get the amount from the text.
var message = "This is a sample message"; // TODO: Get the message from the text.

// now write out the variables
Console.WriteLine("username: " + username);
Console.WriteLine("amount: " + amount);
Console.WriteLine("message: " + message);
```

Comment: Have you even tried? There are plenty of good tools for building  Regexes, such as [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) or [Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

Comment: I am challenged when it comes to regular expressions :-) I've been doing stuff like text.substring(0, text.indexOf('@'.... stuff you don't even want to see. I'm looking for some clean expressions from people that are actually good at this stuff.

Comment: The tools I linked to help you build expressions, by using them you should have no problems doing what you need to do for parsing these simple strings. I prefer regexes to "manual" parsing because this allows you to declaratively define the pattern which you want to match instead of imperatively search for parts; thereby you get input validation "for free" with the regex (if the pattern doesn't match, the input was invalid).

Answer (score 4):

You can use capturing groups:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^Cashpay\s+@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.+)$");
var text = "Cashpay @username 55 This is a sample message";

var match = regex.Match(text);

if (!match.Success)
    //Bad string! Waaaah!

string username = match.Groups[1].Value;
int amount = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
string message = match.Groups[3].Value;
```

Comment: I like the `throw new Exception("Waaaah!")`

Comment: @SLacks: Fair point it should have been `FormatException` or `SLaksException`.

Comment: nice, only the int should prolly be double or decimal if its supposed to be a monetary value.

Answer (score 3):

This method does not do input validation; in some cases this might be ok (e.g. the input is coming from a source which has already been validated).  If you are getting this from user input you should probably use a method that is more robust.  If it is coming from a trusted source but has multiple formats (e.g. "Cashpay" is one of many choices) you could use a switch or if statement for flow control after the split:

```
// make sure you validate input (coming from trusted source?) 
// before you parse like this.

string list[] = text.Split(new char [] {' '});

if (list[0] == "Cashpay")
{
    var username = list[1].SubString(1);
    var amount = list[2];
    var message = string.Join(' ',list.Skip(3));
}
```

or

```
// make sure you validate input (coming from trusted source?) 
// before you parse like this.

string list[] = text.Split(new char [] {' '},4);

if (list[0] == "Cashpay")
{
    var username = list[1].SubString(1);
    var amount = list[2];
    var message = list[3];
}
```

Comment: nice and simple. The only thing is the message gets truncated when using list[3] because it has a space in it.

Comment: `message = String.Join(" ", list.Skip(3))`.  Note that you should `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: But as-is it will fail to parse the message and you don't have validation of the input built-in. This kind of code will throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` somewhere after the split which is not really a good way of dealing with invalid input.

Comment: @Slack -- like yours better than my join with 4 params.

Comment: @SLaks, @Hogan: why not use the correct overload of [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) instead of merging the message at the end?

Comment: @Lucero#2: I'd forgotten about that overload.  Also, my version is simpler.

Comment: @Lucero#1: That's the advantage to the regex version.  This code also doesn't check that it starts with `Cashpay`.

Comment: @Paul - I was in mid-edit... sorry about the truncation, both should work now.

Comment: @SLaks, I'm all for the regex version because this is the right tool for pattern matching. Just like I use a screwdriver when I have screws, and only a hammer whan I have nails. Using the hammer for screws may seem to work, but it's a botch. In regards to parsing, if it is more complex than simple patterns than I always use a proper grammar and a LALR parser... ;)